# JetPack Navigation - Missing 'graph' attribute in <include> tag

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm starting to use navigation component and my hierarchy is :

I have a layout named `nav_graph` and is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/featureHomeNavGraph">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/featureHomeNavGraph"
        app:graphResName="feature_home_nav_graph"
        app:moduleName="feature_home" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/featureFavouritesNavGraph"
        app:graphResName="feature_favourites_nav_graph"
        app:moduleName="feature_favourites" />

    ...
</navigation>
```

And then I've created the layouts as :

`feature_home_nav_graph.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:moduleName="feature_home"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment"
        app:moduleName="feature_home" />
</navigation>
```

`feature_favourites_nav_graph.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:moduleName="feature_favourites"
    app:startDestination="@id/favouritesFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/favouritesFragment"
        android:name="FavouritesFragment"
        android:label="FavouritesFragment"
        app:moduleName="feature_favourites" />
</navigation>
```

But I'm getting this error when running the app

> error: Missing 'graph' attribute in  tag.

And this one too

> Navigation XML document  element must contain a app:graph attribute, whose value begins with @navigation/.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `include`s that are missing the `app:graph` attribute. It should be:

```
<include
    app:graph="@id/featureHomeNavGraph"
    ... />
```

and so on. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs?hl=en#include).

Comment: Then I remove the `graphResName` and `moduleName`?

Comment: These attributes are [<include-dynamic/>](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-dynamic#included) specific.